# Original bitcoin core has one script.cpp.where is interepreter for it?I want to write hello world compiler to understand this.?

Tags: script

How to understand script.cpp and its interpreter.I understand register and postfix operation.
I want to understand how script is parsed into machine code.Can i write hello world such as only pushing value into the stack.

Comment: You mean where in the source code in the original Bitcoin v0.1 source code was the script interpreter? It was in script.cpp: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.1.5/script.cpp#L44L806

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand how script is parsed into machine code.

Unlike Ethereum, Script isn't compiled. It's interpreted, like Javascript. The opcodes are evaluated on-the-fly.

> Can I write hello world such as only pushing value into the stack?

Maybe try entering

```
0x0c 0x48656c6c6f20776f726c6421
```

to https://matiu.github.io/opcodes-playground/? (`0x0c` is the length of the text, as a push operation)